# LDAP Replication

Tags: ldap, replication

I'm trying to use LDAP Sync Replication.  I must grant rights to my account replicador.  This is my ldif:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs = userPassword,shadowLastChange by
 self write by anonymous auth by
 dn="cn=admin,dc=nfsseixas,dc=br" write by
 dn="cn=replicador,dc=nfsseixas,dc=br" read by * none
-
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
-
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {2}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=nfsseixas,dc=br" write by * read
```

I'm following the steps but I cannot see what I'm doing wrong!

when I do this:

```
ldapmodify -c -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f replica2.ldif
```

The result is:

```
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
    additional info: <olcAccess> handler exited with 1
```

Comment: ...have you looked in your (LDAP server) log files to see what's going on?

Comment: it's OpenLDAP I presume...